# What's the differences between XML 2.1 and 3.0?

Tags: xml

What's the differences between XML 2.1 and 3.0?
When you load it from MS .Net, how do you identify which version it is?

I don't have much experience on XML. Thanks for your input.

Comment: XML only has versions [1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) and [1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/). Are you talking about some sort of .NET library? Can you provide links to that library's documentation?

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about XSLT, or XPath? There was a draft of "XPath 2.1", which was then renumbered "XPath 3.0" while still at draft status.

Comment: There's a candidate recommendation at W3C for [Canonical XML Version 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-xml-c14n2-20120124/), but obviously lucyzhu is asking about some sort of Microsoft product, perhaps the XML Document Object Model (DOM) connected with [versions of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87(v=vs.80).aspx).